# using php and regex to change @import to php include?

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

Very very long story short, I am basically trying to use a regex (or maybe even string replace) to change

```
@import url('narf.css');
```

to

```
<?php include('narf.css'); ?>
```

So far, I have come up with this, BUT it does not close the PHP tag....

```
$var =  str_replace('@import url', '<?php include', $var);
```

Aside from this, I am kinda stuck.  I am HORRIBLE at regex syntax and everything I have tried or tried to look up has lead me down a dead end road.

Any help would be MORE than appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just append it `. "?>"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$var = preg_replace('/@import url\(([^)]+)\);/', '<?php include $1; ?>', $var);
```

To break it down:

1. `@import url\(` - literally matches **@import url(**.
2. `([^)]+)` - Captures everything inside the parenthesis into the first back-reference.
3. `\);` - literally matches **);**.

If you have some whitespace somewhere in there, you's have to account for that too...

Comment: beautiful!  however, it did also strip out the () on the php part, ending up with <?php include 'narf.css' ?> instead of <?php include ('narf.css') ?>

My main hump was the ([^)]+) .  That's what I always syntaxually got wrong. :)  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @PaulHanak - Either way is valid PHP. Why do you want the parenthesis?

Comment: LOL Sorry about that Joseph.  I have been looking at that so long.  You are correct. Both are valid. :)